# Как можно сделать автообновление при сохранении файлов php

Tags: php, xampp

Использую xampp как локальный сервер, Как можно сделать автообновление страницы при сохранении файлв PHP?

Comment: О каком сохранении файлов php вы ведёте речь?

Comment: @ArchDemon, об обычном в любом редакторе. Какое ещё может быть?))

Comment: т. е. вам лень нажать F5 в браузере? Хорошо что вы на java сайты не пишите. Ждать когда 200 мб сайт загрузиться на хост - то ещё занятие

Comment: @ArchDemon, ооох уж дожили)))

Answer (score 0):

Для браузера Хром есть специальное расширение - Tincr.
Делает обновление страницы после сохранения файла.

Еще несколько решений на англ. версии сайта - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588658/auto-reload-browser-when-i-save-changes-to-html-file-in-chrome